# How to write data as binary in excel file created in memory

Tags: python, excel, binary, xlsxwriter

I have an excel file created in memory using  python xlswriter. How do i write data into it as binary? I am trying to reduce the size of the file.

Comment: what do you mean by "write data into it as binary"?

Comment: I dont want to write data onto excel file as string or unicode. I want the binary data to be written onto it.

Comment: but unicode is written as binary, i don't see what you mean. Do you mean instead of writing a string such as "101", litterally writing the binary number 5?

Comment: More like binary excel file (.xlsb).

Comment: Afaik xlsxwriter cannot use xlsb